# Wakanda : Modify field on entry creation

Tags: javascript, wakanda

I am currently making an app for punching in and out employees.

I have three tables, one for the Employes, one for the PunchIn and one for the PunchOut.

[image: Diagram]

What I want is the following : when I create a PunchIn, it change the `is_in` entry (of the table Employees) to `true` and when I create a PunchOut, the `is_in` is false.

How can I deal with relations to make this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the employee entity already exists, it's just:

```
punchInEntity.Employee.is_in = true;
```

and

```
punchOutEntity.Employee.is_in = false;
```

Be sure to save both entities afterward:

```
punchOutEntity.save();
punchOutEntity.Employee.save();
```

However, you might want to consider making `is_in` a computed attribute. In it's method, you could search for a `punchOutCollection` entity that is after the current date/time. Return false if one is found and true if not (as long as there is at least one `punchInCollection` entity). That way, you don't have to worry about updating `is_in` and it will always be correct.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you may want to change the Employee attribute names to employee to match the convention of beginning attribute names with lowercase. While we're at it, why not rename punchInCollection and punchOutCollection to punchIns and punchOuts?

Answer (score 0):

Relations are not the best use case here. You need your employee entity to create a Punchin entity. So, why not directly update your employee entity instead of using relations ?

An example:

```
var emp = ds.Employees.find("ID = 1");
var myPunchin = new ds.Punchin({
    employee: emp
});
myPunchin.save();

myPunchin.employee.is_in = true;
myPunchin.employee.save();
```

Even better without relations, you can replace `myPunchin.employee` by `emp`.